# Date counting in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a simple way in Ruby to count the number of days from YYYY-MM-DD to another YYYY-MM-DD and list them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Date.parse('2010-01-01').upto(Date.parse('2010-01-31')) do |day|
  puts day
end
```

Or:

```
(Date.parse('2010-01-01')..Date.parse('2010-01-31')).each do |day|
  puts day
end
```

Comment: `String#to_date` is not defined in plain ruby.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Date.parse` to convert the strings to `Date` objects and then simply use the two `Date` objects in a range and call `to_a` on that range. I.e.:

```
( Date.parse(string1) .. Date.parse(string2) ).to_a
```